# Navbar: layout-align="space-between stretch" doesn't behave correctly

Tags: css, flexbox, angular-material

I'm trying to align some of my links on top of the navbar and some of them (Logout, Enter Fullscreen) at the bottom:

[image]

But as you can see it doesn't work.
This is my html code for the navbar:

```
<section layout="row" flex>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" layout-align="space-between stretch" flex>
        <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo" layout="row">
            <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Menu</h1>
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="close" ng-click="close()">
                <md-icon md-svg-icon="assets/img/closeNavbar.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </md-toolbar>
        <div layout="column" layout-align=" center">
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.overview">Overview</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.caseOverview">Cases</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.errorTotal">Total Errors</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.totalVehicles">Total Vehicles</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.errorTotalDonuts">Error Types</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.mapCluster">Map</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.mapLive">Live Map</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.manufacturers">Manufacturers</md-button>
        </div>

        <div layout="column" layout-align=" center" flex>
            <md-button ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="login">Logout</md-button>
            <md-button ng-click="toggleFullscreen()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left">{{fullscreenButtonLabel}}</md-button>
        </div>

    </md-sidenav>

</section>
```

I already tried to add some "height:100%" css to divs but that only accomplished that an unnecessary scrollbar appeared.
What do I have to change to make this alignment possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, hope is helping you.

```
<section layout="row" flex>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" layout-align="space-between stretch" flex>
        <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo" layout="row">
            <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Menu</h1>
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="close" ng-click="close()">
                <md-icon md-svg-icon="assets/img/closeNavbar.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </md-toolbar>
        <div layout="column" layout-align=" center">
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.overview">Overview</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.caseOverview">Cases</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.errorTotal">Total Errors</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.totalVehicles">Total Vehicles</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.errorTotalDonuts">Error Types</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.mapCluster">Map</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.mapLive">Live Map</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="insurance.manufacturers">Manufacturers</md-button>
        </div>

        <div class="logout" layout="column" layout-align=" center" flex>
            <md-button ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="login">Logout</md-button>
            <md-button ng-click="toggleFullscreen()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left">{{fullscreenButtonLabel}}</md-button>
        </div>

    </md-sidenav>

</section>

.md-sidenav-left{
position:relative;
}

.logout{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: It did work with a little adjustment:
.logout{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

and without the sidenav css stuff
Thank you!